# Hazelcast Jet 0.6.1 - Compilation error with Pipeline customTransform API

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I am getting following compilation error with Pipeline `customTransform` API.

Here is sample code for building pipeline:

```java
private Pipeline buildPipeline2() {
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    p.drawFrom(Sources.<String, CacheEntry<AuditLogRecord>>remoteMapJournal("cache_AuditLog", getClientConfig(), START_FROM_OLDEST))
          .addTimestamps((v) ->  getTimeStamp(v), 3000)
          .peek()
          .groupingKey((v) -> Tuple2.tuple2(getUserID(v),getTranType(v)))
    .window(WindowDefinition.sliding(SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH_MILLIS, SLIDE_STEP_MILLIS))
    //.aggregate(counting(),(winStart, winEnd, key, result) -> String.format("%s %5s %4d", toLocalTime(winEnd), formatKey(key), result))
    .aggregate(counting())
    .map((v)-> getMapKey(v))
    .customTransform("test2", ()-> this)
    .drainTo(Sinks.map("Test"));
    //.drainTo(Sinks.files("c:\\data\\op.txt"));
    return p;
  }
```

Here is sample code for `tryProcess()` method:

```java
protected boolean tryProcess(int ordinal, Object item) {
    JetEvent jetEvent = (JetEvent)item;
    Object obj = jetEvent.payload();
    tryEmit(ordinal,item);
    return true;
}
```

Here is compilation error.

```
incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
[ERROR] inferred: java.lang.Object
[ERROR] upper bound(s): java.util.Map.Entry
```

This compiles and runs well with following code.

```
 .customTransform("test2", ()-> this)
 .drainTo(Sinks.files("c:\\data\\op.txt"));
```

However,the gives compilation error with following code.

```
.customTransform("test2", ()-> this)
.drainTo(Sinks.map("Test"));
```

Will you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Most probably it doesn't work with the `map` Sink because it expects a complete `Map.Entry` instance with the key and value. And you're extracting just key from it at the step `.map((v)-> getMapKey(v))`, so that only `JetEvent` object goes further into the Sink. And then it thows the error.

Answer (score 0):

`customTransform` isn't type-safe. If the type parameter can't be inferred, it will evaluate to `Object`. However, the `Sinks.map` requires `Map.Entry<K, V>`. To resolve it, add type hint to the `customTransform` method:

```java
    .<Map.Entry<YourKeyType, YourValueType>customTransform("test2", ()-> this)
    .drainTo(Sinks.map("Test"));
```

Keep in mind that if your custom processor doesn't actually return `Map.Entry`, it will fail at runtime.

The `Sinks.files` works because it takes `Object`.